# libxml2 - what does the field ExternalID in xmlParseDTD mean

Tags: xml, dtd, libxml2

what should i plug in the field "ExternalID " of xmlParseDTD?
what is ExternalID ?

Answer (score 1):

here is the [documentation on XML](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#NT-ExternalID):

```
[75]    ExternalID     ::=      'SYSTEM' S SystemLiteral
                                 | 'PUBLIC' S PubidLiteral S SystemLiteral
```

for example it is the part

```
PUBLIC "-//Textuality//TEXT Standard open-hatch boilerplate//EN"
"http://www.textuality.com/boilerplate/OpenHatch.xml"
```

of

```
<!ENTITY open-hatch
     PUBLIC "-//Textuality//TEXT Standard open-hatch boilerplate//EN"
     "http://www.textuality.com/boilerplate/OpenHatch.xml">
```

Comment: I didn't understand.  What is ExternalID?  is it the url?

Comment: It is the whole string - "(PUBLIC | SYSTEM) [PubidLiteral] SystemLiteral". In your case i guess the DTD is available on your system so you should write SYSTEM "http://yourdomain.com/your.dtd"

Comment: What is the difference between public and system?

Comment: System DTD's are internal to the system and you just point the url to it, public DTD's have been published for public use therefore need to be uniquely named. For example HTML 4 DTD is publicly available therefore you write <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">

Comment: Thanks, and what is the public literal, how are they built?

Comment: It's just a unique name for your DTD that in many cases is formed as -//<creators_name>//<dtd_name>//<language>, however this structure is not predefined by the standard. Take a look at http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#NT-PubidLiteral